# How to monitor Adaptec Raid on ESXi 5.0

Tags: vmware-esxi

Just wanted to ask if anyone of you knows how can I monitor or install a diagnostic tool for adaptec raid card on ESXi 5.0 running plaform? Or any .vim package that I can install in esxi os. We are using an oem server running on Intel MotherBoard S5500BC. Any answers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the Adaptec card you have installed.

See this table from Adaptec: [ESX 5i support for Adaptec RAID cards](http://ask.adaptec.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17086/kw/cim)

You should search for CIM Provider for your card. Find an example driver [here](http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/speed/raid/storage_manager/cim_vmware_v7_31_18856_zip.htm) which includes RemoteARCCONF to configure the card remotely and monitor it remotely.

Comment: Hi MichelZ, Many thanks for your reply! I will try to configure it using the link you've provided. Our adaptec raid card model is 5506. I hope it is included in adaptec CIM provider.

Comment: Did that ever work? I can get RemoteARCCONF to 'talk' to the controller via a Windows box. But I cannot see the storage status on ESXi's Hardware status. My Controller is 5805 and according to Adaptec it supports CIM